# How to prevent variable from being changed to "None" if the field is blank in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read a cell in an excel file and assign it to a variable. The problem comes when the cell is blank. Then the variable is assigned the string "None". I want it to be blank (""). Is there an easy way of doing this in one line in Python? Something like this?

```
  a = str(sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value) if (a != "None") else: a = ""
```

My goal is to achieve this without writing (sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value), multiple times. Since i have a lot of other variables to check and that makes it harder to maintain.

Comment: Why are you casting to a string?

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is dangerous if you ever have a cell with the value "None". The most pythonic way to do this is in two lines:

```
v = sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value
a = str(v) if v is not None else ''
```

Writing `sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value` multiple times causes unnecessary accesses to the sheet object, so your goal of avoiding it is good. However, your goal of writing it in one line should be secondary to the goal of writing it well.

Comment: one could be tempted to write `v = str(sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value or "")` but if the cell contains numeric zero that wouldn't work as intended

Answer (score 1):

A couple of one-liners, that aren't going to replace a good old "assign then test" 2-line method:

Create a generator and iterate on a one-element list, which allows to assign to a variable, then use a ternary on this variable, use `next` to iterate once and get the value:

```
v = next("" if x is None else str(x) for x in [sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value])
```

Maybe more interesting: if the values cannot be 0, you could use `or`:

```
v = str(sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value or "")
```

now is it worth saving one line? I'll let you figure it out.

Comment: I too prefer the readability of boolean comparisons `if … else` but, of course, 0 is also `False`. As are more generally, `[]` and `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can split it in a couple of lines, it will feel better, and you have several options:

```
res = str(sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value)
a = "" if res == "None" else res
```

or another option for example:

```
a = {"None" : ""}.get(res, res)
```